# Sintaxis error key controller ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, javascript-metodo, javascript-import, three.js

buen dìa.
Tengo un error en la sintaxis me aparece este error en Javascript intentando mover un cubo con las letras del teclado "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'keyController' has already been declared (at linea 35)".

Este es mi archivo keyController donde da el error

```
const keyController = new KeyController()

export default keyController

export{ KeyController }
```

Y este el index.js

```
import camera from './basic/Camera.js';
import light from './basic/Light.js';
import renderer from './basic/Renderer.js';
import scene from './basic/Scene.js';
import resize from './basic/Resize.js';
import cube from './basic/shapes/Cube.js';
import plane from './basic/shapes/Plane.js'
import loopMachine from './basic/LoopMachine.js';
import keyListener from './basic/keyListener.js';
import { keyCode } from './basic/KeyCode.js';
import characterController from './controller/CharacterController.js';
import keyController from './controller/KeyController.js';
import moveController from './controller/MoveController.js';

scene.add(cube);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(plane);

camera.position.set(2,2,2);

camera.lookAt(cube.position);

characterController.addCharacter(cube)
characterController.addController(keyController)
characterController.addController(moveController)

loopMachine.addCallback(() => {
    if(keyListener.isPressed(keyCode.ENTER)) cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);    
});

resize.start(renderer);
loopMachine.start();
keyListener.start();
characterController.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya has declarado la variable `keyController` en tu archivo `keyController.js`. Esto puede suceder si has importado o declarado la variable en otro lugar de tu código.

Debes asegurarte de que solo declaras la variable keyController una vez en tu código. En este caso, parece que ya has importado y declarado la variable en el archivo `keyController.js`, por lo que no es necesario volver a importarla en el archivo index.js.

Archivo keyController.js:

```
class KeyController {
  // tu implementación de KeyController
}

const keyControllerInstance = new KeyController();

export default keyControllerInstance;
export { KeyController };
```

y el index.js quedaria asi:

```
import camera from './basic/Camera.js';
import light from './basic/Light.js';
import renderer from './basic/Renderer.js';
import scene from './basic/Scene.js';
import resize from './basic/Resize.js';
import cube from './basic/shapes/Cube.js';
import plane from './basic/shapes/Plane.js';
import loopMachine from './basic/LoopMachine.js';
import keyListener from './basic/keyListener.js';
import { keyCode } from './basic/KeyCode.js';
import characterController from './controller/CharacterController.js';
import keyControllerInstance from './controller/KeyController.js'; // Cambio de nombre aquí
import moveController from './controller/MoveController.js';

// Resto de tu código
```

Comment: Me sigue dando error en el keyController.js linea 1 
```
import keyCode from "../basic/KeyCode.js"
import keyListener from "../basic/keyListener.js
```

Comment: eso es otra cosa, fijate si el orden de importacion es relevante...